# How to set value from a select split condition to a column?

Tags: mysql

I have a column (location) in a table that has values like that "Province>City>ZIPCode".
I create some new columns: province - city - zipcode
and now i'm trying to set value from split condition to a column.

this query actually works fine:

UPDATE tbl_name
set province = SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'>', 1) where ID = 123;

the table has about 20k records, and i need to set values for all rows.
Something like "WHERE ID = ID"

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query for updating data with select statement

```
UPDATE tbl_name set province = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'>', 1))
```

Comment: MySQL said:Documentation

#1406 - Data too long for column 'province' at row 487

Comment: it seems that 'province' column length is not sufficient for the supplied data. just try to increase the data length of the column